# Escaping brackets in regexp

Tags: regular-expressions

I tried these two, but none of them worked.

```
(if (looking-at "\[") (insert "f"))

(if (looking-at "[") (insert "f"))
```

How can I escape square brackets in emacs regexp?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this:

```
(if (looking-at "\\[") (insert "f"))
```

Usually you will need to escape your escaping backslash. [This tutorial](http://ergoemacs.org/emacs/elisp_regex.html) has a short explanation of the "double backslash".

When in doubt, I always use the built-in [`re-builder`](https://www.masteringemacs.org/article/re-builder-interactive-regexp-builder). If you try this on a buffer with `[` in it, you will find that `"\\["` will match them. Pressing `C-c C-w` in the `re-builder` will copy the regular expression to your kill-ring to yank back into the function you are working on.

Comment: [This answer](http://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/5577/2823) has more detail on using re-builder, and when escaping is necessary.

Answer (score 5):

All you need is this: **`(if (looking-at "[[]") (insert "f"))`**.

In general, "special" regexp characters are not special within brackets.

See the Elisp manual, node [Regexp Special](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Regexp-Special.html). It tells you this about special chars and bracketed char classes:

> Note also that the usual regexp special characters are not special
>   inside a character alternative.  A completely different set of
>   characters is special inside character alternatives: ‘]’, ‘-’ and
>   ‘^’.
>
> To include a ‘]’ in a character alternative, you must make it the
>   first character.  For example, ‘[]a]’ matches ‘]’ or ‘a’.  To
>   include a ‘-’, write ‘-’ as the first or last character of the
>   character alternative, or put it after a range.  Thus, ‘[]-]’
>   matches both ‘]’ and ‘-’.  (As explained below, you cannot use ‘]’
>   to include a ‘]’ inside a character alternative, since ‘\’ is not
>   special there.)

Comment: `(font-lock-add-keywords 'sql-mode '( ("\[[^]]*\]" . font-lock-function-name-face) ))` does not work. How do I include `]` char in a list of "excluded chars"?

Comment: @Adobe: Define "does not work" - it's not clear what you're trying to do or what you're doing and what you're seeing. Anyway, it looks like you have an extra `[`. Did you try `"\[^]]*\]`? That excludes `]`. It makes little sense to write `\[[^]\]`, which says match *either* `[` *or* anything other than newline and `]`. The second set of chars includes the first.

Comment: I wanted a regexp that matches thing in square brackets including square brackets themselves to be on function-name face. However `"\[[^]]*\]"` applies only to empty square brackets. I think this regexp means: "looking for something that starts with square bracket, followed by any number of any chars but new line and square bracket, and ends with square bracket as well".

Comment: No. It doesn't. Everything between `\[` and `\]` represents one character - *any* character of those specified. You follow that by `*`, meaning zero or more of them. Nothing in what you wrote specifies `[` followed by... Please consult the Elisp manual, node [Syntax of Regexps](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Syntax-of-Regexps.html) and its subnodes.