# Has matches , but re-builder print "No matches"

Tags: regular-expressions

Emacs 26.1

In *scratch* buffer I has text

```
KRW-EOS
hel-how
hello-how-ar
h-privet
kak-del
123-567
aaa-bbb
AAA-BBB
AAAA-BBBB
AAA-BB
AA-BBB
A-A
AAAAAAAAAA BBBBBB
AAA BBB
ZZZ-YYY

M-x regexp-builder
```

Input next regexp:

```
\b[A-Z]{3}-\b[A-Z]{3}
```

But I get message: `No matches`

[image]

Why?

`KRW-EOS` - is match!!!

Comment: `{` and `}` match themself and don't have special meaning unless you escape them i.e. `\{` and `\}`, [(elisp) Syntax of Regexps](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Syntax-of-Regexps.html) says "The special characters are ‘.’, ‘*’, ‘+’, ‘?’, ‘[’, ‘^’, ‘$’, and ‘\’;".

Comment: @xuchunyang: Please consider posting your comment as an answer.

Comment: @xuchunyang \b[A-Z]\{3\}-\b[A-Z]\{3\}  - not help. Same result.

Comment: @Alexei `re-builder` supports three different syntaxes to represent one regexp: `read`, `string` and `rx`. Take \b for example, the `read` syntax is `"\\b"` (the same as the actual Emacs Lisp code and `read` stands for Emacs Lisp reader); the `string` syntax is `"\b"` (the same as `C-M-s`, the minibuffer will escape `\` for you); the `rx` syntax is `(rx word-boundary)` (it is also actual Emacs Lisp code but using `rx`).

Comment: @Alexei and the default syntax is `read`, see the variable `reb-re-syntax`, so you need to escape \ by yourself. If you use `string` syntax, then that pattern will work. You can change syntax by changing `reb-re-syntax` or `C-c C-i` (`reb-change-syntax`).

Comment: If re-builder shows “No matches”, then your pattern is definitively **not** a match. Claiming otherwise in your question is nonsensical -- you should be asking what is *wrong* with your regexp, rather than insisting that it is correct.

Comment: Please also refer to https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/5568 which will also help you with the different syntax options.