# regexp-builder - no match with correct regexp. Why?

Tags: regular-expressions

In buffer I has text

```
"ADA-SGD"
"ADT-SGD"
"ADX-SGD"
"AID-SGD"
"AMP-SGD"
"ANT-SGD"
"ARDR-SGD"
"ARK-SGD"

M-x regexp-builder
```

Input regexp:

```
"\([A-Z]+\)-\([A-Z]+\)"
```

But I get message:

```
No match.
```

[image]

Why?

Comment: Try `"\\\([A-Z]+\\\)-\\\([A-Z]+\\\)"`. Also take a look at this answer https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/5577/9970

Comment: It's work. But so much "\". Has any simpler method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two (2) backslashes are sufficient to get the job done:

```
"\\([A-Z]+\\)-\\([A-Z]+\\)"
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably you want to select the `string` syntax.

```
  (setq reb-re-syntax 'string)
```

[re-syntax](https://www.masteringemacs.org/article/re-builder-interactive-regexp-builder)

Comment: @Alexei see also the comments to your [basically-a-duplicate](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/46900) question from a few days ago.