# How to paste a multiline regex from re-builder into `replace-regexp`

Tags: regular-expressions, replace

I built with `M-x re-builder` a regex to match empty quoted lines in emails. In `read` syntax it is:

```
"^>\\s-*\n>"
```

How can I copy this regex in re-builder, so that I can paste it in the first prompt of `M-x replace-regexp`?

**I tried the following:**

After writing the regex in re-builder's `read` mode I switched with `Ctrl-C TAB` to `string` syntax and copied the regex via `Ctrl-C Ctrl-w`. Then I issued `M-x replace-regexp` and pasted the regex but found "0 occurrences". Additionally I deleted the `"` quotes characters from the pasted text and try again, but still got no matches. I guess, something goes wrong with the newline character...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're almost doing the right thing -- switch to `string` syntax, and copy the pattern, sans the double-quotes.

You need to copy it directly from the re-builder buffer using the *normal* copy/kill commands though, as `C-c C-w` always gives you the regexp in read syntax.

Regarding the newline, that should be a literal newline character at this point, and *not* the escape sequence `\n` (which won't match a newline in this syntax).

Comment: I'll also link to https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/5568/454 in case any of that is useful (although you clearly understand the key parts of that already).

Comment: Thanks, that's it. Copying by hand is the way to do it. - A bit strange though that `C-c C-w` doesn't do it...

Comment: You should `M-x report-emacs-bug` for a feature-request.  I think an option to copy in the current syntax would be useful.

Comment: Done. :-) I have report this to the emacs bugs list