# Help with regex in re-builder : lines without "|" nor ";" at the beginning

Tags: regular-expressions

I am starting regex with Emacs and cannot get the right regex.
I would like to match the line `1` and `4` in the image below, where `variable-pitch` is "active" and do not match `2` and `3` where is "inactive"

so I am basically trying to say :

`line with 'variable-pitch' not containing with ";" or "|"`

[image]

Following [this post](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/5568/why-do-regular-expressions-created-with-the-regex-builder-use-syntax-different-f), I switched re-builder to `string` mode.

Edit : Following the different comments

- [here is the text](https://jpst.it/2owX2) if you want to try
- i changed the the screenshot with `re-builder` actually set to string

Comment: Anchor your regex.

Comment: If you also posted that content as plain text, people could test against it.

Comment: @phils : done sharing, see edit

Comment: @user1683620: You can install ix from elpa (package-install 'ix). Just M-x ix and you get a link to a pastebin on your buffer. Very fast and convenient to transmit text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I switched re-builder to `string` mode

Did you?  You've used `\\(...\\)` to (apparently successfully) match a sub-group, which indicates you're using `read` syntax.  In `string` syntax that would be `\(...\)`.

---

Regarding this:

```
[^;|\\|].*\\(variable-pitch.*\\)
```

`[^;|\\|]` says to match anything other than `;`, `|`, `\`, or (again) `|`.  Note also that newlines are not excluded.

Following that you match `.*`, which is zero or more non-newline characters.

Finally you match a subgroup consisting of `variable-pitch` followed by zero or more non-newline characters.

---

> so I am basically trying to say: line with 'variable-pitch' not containing with ";" or "|"

So something like this?

```
"^[^;|\n]*variable-pitch[^;|\n]*$"
```

Note that you can only use `\n` in `read` syntax (because it's an escape sequence for reading strings, not an escape sequence for regexps).  If you're using `string` syntax in re-builder then you'll need to type a literal newline instead.

Comment: Thanks for you help. I tested your proposition and updated the screenshot accordingly. It looks like it matches anyway line 2 et 3 whereas it should not.

Comment: Whoops.  Despite having mentioned this, I also forgot to exclude newlines from my character alternatives.  I've updated the pattern.