# How to match a single ')' with replace-regex?

Tags: spacemacs, regular-expressions, parentheses

I want to replace a list in the form of

```
1)
2)
3)
4)
```

with

```
* 
*
*
```

I've tried using the regex `[0-9]*\)`, but it gives `Invalid regexp: "Unmatched ) or \\)"` and `[0-9]*\\)` replaces 0 matches.
in `regex-builder`, `[0-9]*\)` matches the expected items.

I'm using `spacemacs 0.300.0` on `emacs 26.3`

Comment: In Emacs, the meaning of parentheses are inverse, compared to many other regexp systems. `(` match a parenthesis whereas `\(` start a regexp group. (When written as a string, the latter is written `"\\("`.)

Answer (score 1):

On writing this question, I found the (very simple) answer, so I'll put it out there for anyone else who finds this confusing (considering I found no similar questions).

It seems that the default behaviour for `replace-regexp` is matching parenthesis literally, so the solution was just `[0-9]*)` and for the usual group capturing is instead `\(group\)`, maybe some configuration or variable changes this.

TL;DR: use `)` with `replace-regexp` for literal matches

Comment: I imagine you want `[0-9]+`, not `[0-9]*`.

Comment: There's no configuration or variable to change this.  Emacs regexps are just nearer to BRE than ERE when it comes to basic syntax.

Comment: There is also `rx` however, which is a way of expressing Emacs regexps as structured expressions; and for `regexp-builder` https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/5568 might be helpful.