# Matching non-# in Regexp

Tags: query-replace-regexp

I'm trying to use replace-regexp to change the following code

```
samples <- rep(10, 5)*1000  ## steps determined by samples * thin
adaptive.ratio <- c(rep(c(1,0), 2), 0) ## Alternate between adaptive and non-adaptive
...
```

to

```
print(paste0("samples: ", samples)) ## steps determined by samples * thin
print(paste0("adaptive.ratio: ", adaptive.ratio)) ## Alternate between adaptive and non-adaptive
...
```

I am using the following regexp to do so

```
^\(\b.*\b\)\([^#]*\) → print(paste0("\1: ", \1) ) \2
```

But this highlights

```
samples <- rep(10, 5)*1000  ## steps determined by samples * thin
adaptive.ratio <- c(rep(c(1,0), 2), 0)
```

for the first replacement rather than what I want, which is to highlight only

```
print(paste0("samples: ", samples)) ## steps determined by samples * thin
```

I've tried escaping the # sign with #, adding a space between the two sets of parentheses,  but that doesn't help.

I realize this is somehow related to the greedy nature of regexp matching, but I don't understand what am I doing wrong nor, as a result, how to fix it.

Comment: I think I know my issue with `\b` matching more than the first set of characters, it's due to the `.*` in between them which should match anything, including things that aren't word boundaries.  I still don't understand, however, why the matching goes beyond the the new line

Comment: Greedy `.*` matches the maximum.  Non-greedy `.*?` matches the minimum.  Although you would want `\b.+?\b` rather than `\b.*?\b` to avoid matching the same `\b` twice.

Comment: As you've already established, while `.` does not match newlines, `[^#]` does.

Comment: Try `M-x re-builder` btw.  It's a good visualiser, especially when the regexp contains groups.  See `M-x finder-commentary RET re-builder` for a description, and https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/5568 may be useful reading as well.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I figured it out.  I was misusing the word boundary markers (which I don't understand how so a comment or two would be great.)

This is the code I want to use

```
^\([A-z0-9_.]+\) \([^# <C-q 012>]*\) → print(paste0("\1: ", \1)
```

Where <C-q 012> inserts the new line character.

Comment: Interactively, you can just use `C-q C-j` to insert a newline char.

Comment: See `C-h i g (elisp)Regexp Backslash` regarding what `\b` matches.

Answer (score 0):

Change your regexp to exclude not only `#` chars but also newline chars.

```
^\(\b.*\b\)\([^#
]*\) → print(paste0("\1: ", \1)) \2
```

That's what you type to interactively type the regexp, where the newline shown is typed using `C-q C-j`.

If you're defining the regexp in Lisp code, as a Lisp string, use this:

```
^\\(\\b.*\\b\\)\\([^#\n]*\\) → print(paste0("\\1: ", \\1)) \\2
```