# How to re-search-forward OR

Tags: regular-expressions, search

How can I match the **values** for the keys (org mode attributes) `#+label` **OR** `#+name`?

Example: Using `get-labels ()` I got `fig:foo`. Nice.

How can I get `fig:bar` as well?

```
#+label: fig:foo
#+name: fig:bar
```

While this one works for `#+label`:

```
(re-search-forward "#\\+label: \\([a-zA-z0-9:-]*\\)" (point-max) t)
```

This one fails i.e. matches only `#+name`:

```
(re-search-forward "#\\+label:\\|#\\+name: \\([a-zA-z0-9:-]*\\)" (point-max) t)
```

---

Used here

```
(defun get-labels ()
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (goto-char (point-min))
    (let ((matches '()))
      (while (re-search-forward "#\\+label: \\([a-zA-z0-9:-]*\\)" (point-max) t)
        (add-to-list 'matches (match-string-no-properties 1) t))
      matches)))
```

.

```
# -*- mode: snippet -*-
# --
cref:${1:$$(yas-choose-value (get-labels))} $0
```

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/tags/elisp/info

Comment: `"#\\+label:\\|#\\+name: \\([a-zA-z0-9:-]*\\)"` is *either* `"#\\+label:"` *or* `"#\\+name: \\([a-zA-z0-9:-]*\\)"`.  Is that what you meant to match?

Comment: @phils `get-labels()` should return `fig:bar` as well. Currently it only returns `fig:foo`

Comment: I highly, *highly* recommend that you spend some time with `M-x re-builder` and experiment with the various kinds of regexp syntax to get your head around them.  Read the regexp sub-sections under  `(emacs)Search` and test the various things to see how they work.  Spending a bit of time doing this should clarify things for you enormously.  Also take note of https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/5568/454.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [`\(...\|...\)`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Regexp-Backslash.html) for grouping:

```
"#\\+\\(label\\|name\\): \\([a-zA-z0-9:-]*\\)"
```

E.g., <kbd>C-j</kbd> (`eval-print-last-sexp`) after `(get-labels)` inserts `("name" "label")`:

```lisp
(defun get-labels ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((matches '()))
    (save-excursion
      (while (re-search-forward "#\\+\\(label\\|name\\): \\([a-zA-z0-9:-]*\\)" (point-max) t)
        (push (match-string-no-properties 1) matches)))
    (delete-dups matches)))
(get-labels)
#+label: fig:foo
#+name: fig:bar
```

PS. You should **never** use [`add-to-list`](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/List-Variables.html#index-add_002dto_002dlist) for a let-bound variables.

Comment: I only got `name` or `NAME` returned. No values from any attribute i.e. `+#name` or `+#label`

Comment: @jjk: WFM, please see the code

Comment: Now yasnippet returns all keys but I need the values

Comment: So replace `(match-string-no-properties 1)` with `(match-string-no-properties 2)`