# Does Emacs have some kind of interactive regular expression editor?

Tags: regular-expressions

I mean something like https://rubular.com/ where I can enter text and experiment with regular expressions to match that text.

Comment: I have found regex-tool on melpa and will try it.

Comment: You can also try `M-x re-builder`. It is shipped with Emacs.

Comment: I have seen it. But is there documentation that explains how to use it?

Comment: https://www.masteringemacs.org/article/re-builder-interactive-regexp-builder Note, you can also switch the syntax via the Re-builder menu.

Comment: Do you understand it? Can you answer additional questions? In regex-tool I can have instant visual feedback when I  try regular expressions and everything is self-explanatory. I do not understand re-builder commands and do not understand what to expect. Do you know of any readable example?

Comment: I don't have much time. But we can try in the following chat: https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/136428/re-builder

Comment: It turns out that my confusion with re-builder was caused by some oddities of trying it in the scratch buffer.

Answer (score 4):

The documentation for `re-builder` is a bit sparse. You can see the basics via `C-h f re-builder`:

> This command makes the current buffer the "target" buffer of
> the regexp builder.  It displays a buffer named "*RE-Builder*"
> in another window, initially containing an empty regexp.
>
> As you edit the regexp in the "*RE-Builder*" buffer, the
> matching parts of the target buffer will be highlighted.

To use it, you open a file with the text you want to test your regexps with. Then you call `M-x re-builder`. A new window will be created at the bottom of the screen, with the empty regexp `""` in it. As you add text to the regexp, matches in the target buffer are highlighted, and match groups are given different colours:

[image]

More details are found at the article @Tobias linked from [Mastering Emacs](https://www.masteringemacs.org/article/re-builder-interactive-regexp-builder)

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/5568 may also be helpful.