# Using query-replace-regex to partially replace

Tags: regular-expressions, query-replace-regexp

I'm struggling with the basics of query-replace-regex after reading the manual.

I'm trying to replace lots of citations formatted like this:
`#123213213, foo bar`

to
`#123213213\, foo bar`

the numbers vary from instance to instance and can be of any length. They always start with a #. Foo bar can be numbers or text. I always want to replace only:

> , --> \,

without changing the numbers or the foo bar.

I've tried emacs' regex builder, and I'm stuck at
`"\#[0-9]*,\s.*\}`
which doesn't work because it selects too much before the bit I want.
Ideally, I'm looking for an answer that explains how it works.
Thanks for your help!

Comment: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/q/5568/454 explains some crucial things about `re-builder`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the trailing arbitrary text can legitimately contain commas, so you can't safely replace every `,` with `\,` throughout:

1. You don't need to escape the `#`.
2. Based on your description, you don't need the `\}`
3. (minor point) You always expect at least one digit in the leading number, correct? Use `+` rather than `*`.

Try this:

```
(query-replace-regexp "#\\([0-9]+\\), \\(.*\\)" "#\\1\\\\, \\2")
```

Interactively, you halve the backslashes:

```
#\([0-9]+\), \(.*\)
RET
#\1\\, \2
RET
```

Comment: If you only reproduce the second match, you can omit it and only keep the `#\([0-9]+\),` part and replace with `#\1\\,`.

Comment: Thank you this answer and comment were both really helpful, and I've solved my particular problem.